# Removing the menu bar in Windows 7 explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I downloaded and set up Windows 8 transformation pack for Windows 7. I wasn't happy with how I did it, so I reverted all system files. Now I have a menu bar in Windows explorer that I can't remove. The `Organize → Layout → Menu bar` checkbox is not checked. How do I remove this?

EDIT: `Tools → Folder options → View → Always show menus` is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu item Tools -> Folder Options.

In page View, uncheck "Always show menus".

Comment: Doesn't work, I edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Organize -> Layout -> uncheck the Menubar

Comment: The question says ''The `Organize → Layout → Menu bar` checkbox is not checked.'', so how can the user uncheck it?